# Woocommerce: Save all products by X times a day

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have this code which update all products. It works fine. But I need to change it.

```
    add_action( 'wp', 'update_products_by_x' );
function update_products_by_x(){

    $limit = 200;

    // getting all products
    $products_ids = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'        => 'product', // or ['product','product_variation'],
        'numberposts'      => $limit,
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'fields'           => 'ids',
        'meta_query'       => array( array(
            'key'     => '_sync_updated',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ) )
    ) );

    // Loop through product Ids
    foreach ( $products_ids as $product_id ) {

        // Get the WC_Product object
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

        // Mark product as updated
        $product->update_meta_data( '_sync_updated', true );

        $product->save();
    }
}
```

The function above marks the updated products as 'updated'. Then this code will save all the products just one time.

**Question:** How do change this function so that I get all products saved every time the function is executed and not just one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** the function will run 5 times a day (max).

If you have many products, you can't update all products.

The following will run each time your website is browsed, and will update a defined number of products each time to avoid problems *(it will run forever, util you will remove it)*:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'update_products_by_x' );
function update_products_by_x(){
    // Get next start time
    $start_time = (float) get_option('product_update_start_time');

    if ( $start_time <= time() ) {
        if ( empty($start_time) || $start_time == 0 ) {
            $start_time = time();
        }

        ## ----- SETTINGS (Below) ----- ##
        $next_time = $start_time + ( 4.8 * 60 * 60 ); // 5 times à day
        $limit     = 200; // Fix the number of products to update each time

        $offset    = (int) get_option('product_update_offset');

        // Get products
        $products_ids = get_posts( array(
            'post_type'        => 'product', // or ['product','product_variation'],
            'numberposts'      => $limit,
            'offset'           => $offset,
            'post_status'      => 'publish',
            'fields'           => 'ids',
        ) );

        $count = count($products_ids);

        if( $count > 0 ) {
            // Loop through product Ids
            foreach ( $products_ids as $product_id ) {
                // Get the WC_Product object
                $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
                $product->save();
            }
            update_option('product_update_offset', ( $count == $limit ? ( $count + $offset ) : 0 ) );
        }
        update_option('product_update_start_time', $next_time);
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: great. One more question: can I make to run this function JUST 5 times by day? I mean that this function will be executed 5 times in a day and then will stop running until the next day.

Comment: @JPashs Updated… This will run 5 times a day max, so each 4.8 hours (or 4h 48mn 00s or 17280 seconds)… Tested and works.